# Params in "where" statement give "missing end" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, controller, syntax-error

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to incorporate if statements within the edit function in the controller. I keep getting an error that says I am missing an end statement, when I know I am not. I wonder if I am supposed to do a "do" statement before the ifs? I am not sure how that would work though.

```
class FiltersController < ApplicationController

(.. other stuff ..) 

def edit
    @filter = Filter.first
    @project = Project.all
    
    if (@filter.date_to =! nil) && (@filter.date_from =! nil)
        if (@filter.project =! nil)
            @hourlogs = Hourlog.where([project_id: @filter.project], ["date >= ?" date_from], ["date <= ?" date_to])
        elsif (@filter.project == nil)
            @hourlogs = Hourlog.where(["date >= ?" date_from, "date <= ?" date_to])
        end
    elsif (@filter.project == nil)
        @hourlogs = Hourlog.all
    else 
        @hourlogs = Hourlog.all
    end
end

(.. more stuff ..) 

end
```

I have end statements for the class, for the edit function, for the first "ifs" and for the second "ifs".

This is the error that I get:

```
/vagrant/src/hourly/app/controllers/filters_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']' ...roject], ["date >= ?" date_from], ["date <= ?" date_to]).ord... ... ^~~~~~~~~ /vagrant/src/hourly/app/controllers/filters_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']' ...ate_from], ["date <= ?" date_to]).order(date: :desc).paginat... ... ^~~~~~~ /vagrant/src/hourly/app/controllers/filters_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']' ...og.where(["date >= ?" date_from, "date <= ?" date_to]).order... ... ^~~~~~~~~ /vagrant/src/hourly/app/controllers/filters_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.' ... date_from, "date <= ?" date_to]).order(date: :desc).paginat... ... ^~~~~~~
```

And here is a photo of it:
[error message for end statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D61iT.png)

I have not included if statements in my controller before, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Based on the articles I read online, this is the correct syntax. Please help.

EDIT: It looks like the issue is caused by the multiple requirements within the where clause, specifically the <= and >= date ones. But I am still stuck.

```
@hourlogs = Hourlog.where([project_id: @filter.project], ["date >= ?" date_from], ["date <= ?" date_to])
```

Any input in terms of how the where statement needs to be structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby use `nil?` when testing if an object is nil. In Rails use `present?` and `blank?` when testing user input as they will reject empty strings as well.

```
def edit
  @filter = Filter.first
  @project = Project.all
  @hourlogs = Hourlog.all
  if @filter.project.present?
    @hourlogs = @hourlogs.where(project_id: @filter.project)
  end
  if @filter.date_to.present? && @filter.date_from.present?
    @hourlogs = @hourlogs.where(date: @filter.date_to..@filter.date_from)
  end
end
```

In Ruby the `not equals` operator is `!=`. Using `unless` is usually preferable though and you do not compare values to nil or true/false like you would in lower level languages. Instead use predicate methods on the object itself - Ruby is a fully object oriented language.

And since `.where` is additive you can just start with a base scope and add more conditions to the where clause by reassigning the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `=!` should be `!=`.

The `where` part should be something like this.

```
@hourlogs = Hourlog
            .where(project_id: @filter.project.id)
            .where(date: date_from...date_to)
```